# Codeigniter 4 ErrorException Undefined variable: table

Tags: codeigniter-4

I am facing this issue of Undefined variable as shown in the image attached which I am not sure what is wrong.

[image]

My code as follows:

Routes

```
$routes->get('account/game_reg', 'Game::index');
$routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'account/game_reg', 'Game::game_reg');
```

Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = [];
        
        if(!session()->get('isLoggedIn')):
            return redirect()->to(base_url('account/login'));
        endif;
        
        $games = new GamelistModel();
        
        $data['table'] = $games->getList();
        
        echo view('templates/header', $data);
        echo view('account/game_reg');
        echo view('templates/footer');
    }

public function game_reg()
    {
        $data = [];
        helper(['form']);
        
        $validation =  \Config\Services::validation();
        
        if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post'){
            
            $user_id = session()->get('user_id');
            
            //validations
            
            $rules = [
                'game_id' => 'required',
                'ign' => 'required|is_unique[game_reg.ign]',
                'acc_id' => 'required'
            ];
            
            $errors = [
                'ign' => [
                    'is_unique' => 'IGN already exist!'
                ],
                'acc_id' => [
                    'is_unique' => 'Account ID already exist!'
                ]
            ];
            
            
            if(!$this->validate($rules, $errors)){
                $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
            }else{
                //store information into database
                
                $model = new GameregModel();
                
                $newData = [
                    'game_id' => $this->request->getVar('game_id'),
                    'ign' => $this->request->getVar('ign'),
                    'acc_id' => $this->request->getVar('acc_id'),
                    'user_id' => session()->get('user_id'),
                    'created_by' => session()->get('username')
                ];
                $model->save($newData);
                $session = session();
                $session->setFlashdata('success', 'Game Successfully Added!');
                return redirect()->to(base_url('account/game_reg'));
                
            }
        }
            
        
        
        echo view('templates/header', $data);
        echo view('account/game_reg');
        echo view('templates/footer');
    }
```

GameregModel

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class GameregModel extends Model{
    
    protected $table = 'game_reg';
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'user_id',
        'game_id',
        'ign',
        'acc_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'created_by'
    ];
    
    
}

?>
```

GamelistModel

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class GamelistModel extends Model{
    
    protected $table = 'game_list';
    protected $primarykey = 'game_id';
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'game_id',
        'game_name'
    ];
    
    public function getList()
    {
        return $this->orderBy('game_id', 'ASC')->findAll();
    }
    
}

?>
```

Views

```
<select id="myDropdown">
                
                    <?php 
                        
                        $i = 1;
                        foreach($table as $t) :
                        $i++;
                        
                    ?>
                    
                    <option value="<?= $t['game_id']; ?>" data-imagesrc="/img/logo_<?= strtolower($t['game_name']); ?>.jpg"><?= $t['game_name']; ?></option>
                    
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    
                </select>
```

If I remove away the is_unique function, everything works perfectly fine but when I include the is_unique, I get the error. What I am trying to do is, I would retrieve a list of games updated by admin, user will then choose from this list and save into their profile.

Hope someone can help me out of this.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: So where are you defining $table and where are you calling/loading this view called views? It's more helpful if you provide the names of the files instead of just what they are... So at this stage I cannot help.

Comment: are you sure $table has always a value, exists always? wrap `foreach($table as $t):` inside a `if(isset($table)): ... endif;`

Comment: @TimBrownlaw and Vickel, Thank you for your help. I have just updated my question with all the codes necessary. What I am trying to do is, I would retrieve a list of games updated by admin, user will then choose from this list and save into their profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only sending the data into one of your views. The one using the $table variable does not have access to it.

So in your loading views code you have to do the following:

```
 echo view('templates/header', $data);
 echo view('account/game_reg', $data);
 echo view('templates/footer', $data);
```

It's better to just send the data across all views.

The other thing I noticed (nothing to do with the problem here) is that you're closing the php tags inside your models. Never do that. Your classes should never have the php closing tag ?>.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I thought the logic is that when I send the data to header file, the data will be accessible for the whole page. Maybe I understand it wrongly. Thanks for pointing out the php tag issue. I didn't know that it should not have closing php tag because I know that if I open, I must close it  so it applies to all my controller and model files, am I right?

Comment: Yes, models, controllers, libraries, etc. Everything that has classes in it should't have a closing tag there. You should only open and close tags in your views.

Comment: @Dr3am3rz Also instead of loading the views a bunch of times seperatly you might want to consider using view layouts. More on that here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/view_layouts.html?highlight=layouts I also made a video explaining on how the views work on codeigniter 4. You can check that ou here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9HQjernJPHN-RoKMwtYQ4w

Comment: Will take a look on that, thank you. Nothing to do with the problem here, based on my controller currently you see, should I just use either index() or game_reg()? Is it a must to have index()?

Comment: @Dr3am3rz It's always a good practice to have a index function in your controllers. That way you can access the default function with just foo.com/controllerName instead of having to do foo.com/controllerName/foobar

Comment: I have added $data to all views and it worked! Also, all my previous issue like is_unique validation have miraculously solved!